# Having Trouble Locating Underlying Document Interface for VS AddIn

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, add-in

When opening a new coding document in Visual Studio I would like add a watermark to the document/page.  I have found the interfaces to interact with document's text selection object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.document.aspx

I've discovered interfaces for font and color of text.

My question is can anyone point me in the right direction for interfacing with the underlying editor so I can add a watermark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an adornment layer with your watermark image. See [Editor Extension Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx) (Adornments) documentation and [VSEditorBackgroundChangerExtension](https://github.com/nategreenwood/VSEditorBackgroundChangerExtension) source code.

Comment: outstanding... this is way more than I was hoping for - thanks!